# Convert select tag from Struts1 to Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I started to convert this select from Struts1 to Struts2.

STRUTS1

```jsp
 <html:select styleId="ss" property="type" styleClass="select2" onchange="checkStatus();">
           <html:options collection="listOfType" property="value" labelProperty="key" />
    </html:select>
```

STRUTS2

```jsp
<s:select id="ss" name="type" cssClass="select2" onchange="checkStatus();">
     ...
</s:select>
```

But I don't know how to convert the options tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list` attribute

```jsp
<s:select id="ss" name="type" cssClass="select2" onchange="checkStatus();"
          list="listOfType" listKey="value" listValue="key"/>
```

You can read more about [`select tag`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html) on Struts docs site.

Comment: documentation link is broken. please update with https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html